# How to repeat a regex group until end of string

Tags: regex

I have the following string
`someaddres.com/?f=[B]a-test,a test,Test[C]test a,test2`

I'm trying to pull two groups from it:

```
[B]a-test,a test,Test
```

and

```
[C]test a,test2
```

How would I repeat the capture group until a character not present in the group is found?

My current regex is: `f=(\[[A-Z]\][a-zA-Z0-9,-\s]+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this regex with a captured group that will match twice:

```
(\[\w+\][^[]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qtZlvM/1)

If you want 2 capture groups in single match then use:

```
(\[\w+\][^[]+)(\[\w+\][^[]+)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/qtZlvM/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `\[`: Match a `[`
  - `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
  - `\]`: Match a `]`
  - [^[]+`: Match 1+ of any characters that is not` [`
- `)`: End capture group #1

Comment: thank you so much! I might have many groups to capture in the same format, is there a way to write that without duping up the logic?

Comment: so say I wanted to capture 5 patterns, Idealy I wouldnt want to dupe this up 5 times

Comment: javascript ECMAScript

Comment: `I wouldn't want to dupe this up 5 times` If regex pattern is exact same as this example then use my first suggested regex that doesn't repeat sub-pattern.

Comment: I've tried adding another group and repeting that to no avail :(

Comment: Ahh I understand now, perfect thank you. You've helped educate me a few times with Regex related questions. Many thanks for your time, a true MVP